# ReactJS + styled-components dynamically sized dropdown menus not working in safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, styled-components

I've made a set of dropdown menus in react using styled-components, which dynamically set their height based on their contents. This works perfectly in chrome and IOS safari but on safari they do not work.

I'm using create-react-app and I have the Browserslist set to 'since-2010' but it still doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried a CSS reset.

The relevant component:

https://github.com/matthewvero/fox-garage/tree/master/src/components/header/header-nav-dropdown

Working example:

https://foxgarage.herokuapp.com

(Dropdowns along the top)

TIA

Comment: When you open the non working example in safari, are there any warnings in the developer tools console log?

Comment: Nothing pertaining to the component unfortunately. @PavlosKaralis

Comment: Are you able to host the non working version? It's difficult to debug otherwise.

Comment: @PavlosKaralis The one linked in the original question is the none working version, it's only not working in Mac safari.  I've just changed the code so that the drop down is always open so you can inspect it. https://foxgarage.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @mattavero Can you try using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` once?

Comment: @AnuragHazra I've changed the code in the component to 

`useLayoutEffect(() => {
            setHeight(dropDownRef.current.firstChild.offsetHeight * dropDownRef.current.children.length)
      }, [height])`

Is this what you mean? No luck.

Comment: hmm yeah.. well try console.log that value you are setting to see if its undefined. also i read somewhere that it can cause because of browser repaint delays... try wrapping that setHeight within a `window.setTimeout(() => {...}, 10)`

Comment: @AnuragHazra Interesting, so on safari it is logging the result of setHeight as 0, but on chrome it is calculating it correctly. I tried the setTimeout but it still isn't calculating the new height. Any ideas? Really appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @AnuragHazra I've just got it working by removing the initial state from the setHeight hook. Not sure why that's done it.